# How can you delete running characters at the end of a string?

Tags: java

Say I had parsed a large number like `130,233,320,000,000,000` into `130,233,320,,,` how could I recursively delete the substring of running commas to get the output like `130,233,320`

A recursive algorithm seems easy like:

```
public String parseEnd(String s) {
  if(s.substring(s.length-1) == ",") {
     return s.substring(0, s.length-2);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: You should never compare strins using `==` operator as in this case. Always use `equals` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
str = str.replaceAll(",+$", "");
```

This replaces one or more `,` at the end, with empty string.

- `,+` matches 1 or more `commas`
- `$` signifies the end of the string.

Now, one thing I don't understand is, how did you got `consecutive commas` from that string? Can't you just replace all the `000` with `comma` directly? This would go something like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?:,0+)+$", "");
```

Comment: @JaneDoh. You're welcome :) And also consider using the 2nd option I posted.

Comment: What does the last regex do? Say I have a unique ID in the form and each section accounts for something unless it is all 0's. So I was just going to take off all the zeros at the end and then get rid of the trailing 0's.